# value property of outerHTML of an element is null

Tags: javascript

i have an element (input) that the user type some value in it and when i get that element by :
document.getElementById 
it has the value (that the user entered), but where get the outerHTML of that element the value property is null

so, how can i get outerHTML of an element with the value ?

Comment: Add your code as a working example please.

Comment: Not exactly sure about what you mean by: ` how can i get outerHTML of an element with the value ?`. A working example as @Sirence suggested would realy help.